# Whats the matter with this rewrite rule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I just wanted to try mod_rewrite and read some stuff about it.

I have this file on localhost:

```
board.php?b=123XYZ
```

And want to archive:

```
board/123XYZ
```

This is what I've got so far: (.htaccess is readable and within the root)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^board/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    board.php?b=$1    [NC,L]
```

But this won't work. I don't understand why as the regex matches.

Comment: What is not working and what is error?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
RewriteRule    ^board\/([aA-zZ0-9-]+)\/?$    board.php?b=$1    [NC,L]
```

I think the forward slashes need to be escaped forward slashes.

This tool helps with regular expression testing:

```
http://regexr.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^board/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ board.php?b=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

You might supposedly getting 404 not found because Apache is assuming incoming url as directory.